# Was Professor McGonagall a Seeker/Quidditch player at School?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

My question is based upon the following frame from the first Harry Potter film (Philosopher's Stone). It shows her name on the right hand side. Well, just wondering, as she's so into Quidditch.

[image: Hogwarts Quidditch Trophy]

Comment: Maybe the dates are right but it's not Prof McGonagall, but a younger relative

Comment: It should also be noted that James Potter was a *chaser*, not a *seeker*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Pottermore article for Professor McGonagall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall) indicates that she was indeed an avid Quidditch player during her school days.

> Minerva was also, like her mother, a gifted Quidditch player, although
>   a nasty fall in her final year (a foul during the Gryffindor versus
>   Slytherin game which would decide the Cup winner) left her with
>   concussion, several broken ribs and a lifelong desire to see Slytherin
>   crushed on the Quidditch pitch. Though she gave up Quidditch on
>   leaving Hogwarts, the innately competitive Professor McGonagall later
>   took a keen interest in the fortunes of her house team, and retained a
>   keen eye for Quidditch talent.

The dates on that trophy are incorrect, however. McGonagall attended Hogwarts from 1947 to 1954 as a member of Gryffindor House. She did not play any Quidditch after she graduated in 1954.

Comment: Oh thank you. Although maybe the dates are a little messed up in the film version, I don't think she was that old when she won one of those trophies? M. G. McGonagall 1971, J. Potter 1972.

Comment: @ManikSethisuwan I confirmed that the dates are, in fact, wrong.

Comment: About the dates, please see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91429/4918 When was Professor McGonagall born?