# How can McGonagall be in the prequels?

Tags: harry-potter, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Professor McGonagall was born in 1935 according to the official timeline. Yet, she appears to be teaching in Hogwarts in 1927, and long before that taught Newt and Leta.

Comment: Related question, possible duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198713/76048

Comment: @F1Krazy definitely looks like it to me

Comment: Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91429/when-was-professor-mcgonagall-born